# Does android have instant preview for Sceneform app?

Tags: android, sceneform

I want to see my 3d scene without having to compile and wait several minutes every time.  Does Android Studio have a similar feature w/ previewing like xcode?

[SceneKit: Material Preview is always black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332998/scenekit-material-preview-is-always-black)

Comment: you need to run it on a phone, but it provides instant run kinda thing

Comment: Are you looking for https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets?